# Router "Wi-Fi module" lagging with no logical cause

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

For some time now, my router has been giving endless issues, especially lagging.

**Router: Netgear DGN2200v2**
Devices Connected:
Wi-Fi - Android Device, 1 Windows PC
LAN - 1 Windows PC

No similar devices/networks operating in the same band/frequency. Router is in an open environment. Connection has always been 100% no issues until about 1 month ago, when this started, at random. No router changes happened before or after.

When connecting to the router, authenticating takes a while and fails about the first 2 times. The wait time is +/- 7 seconds. Then obtaining an IP address (which fails 2-4 times) takes about 10 seconds. After that I can finally connect, but passing any data through the Wi-Fi module of the router, be it connecting to the internet or transferring data over Wi-Fi to anywhere, or even pinging the router, shows this:

http://pastebin.com/GS2ugYx1

**TL;DR** -

-> just pinging, no data flow

```
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=82ms TTL=64 
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=303ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=77ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=129ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=997ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=75ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=261ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=64
```

When entering into the router settings from my Windows PC over Wi-Fi (router has web based settings via browser), clinking on link in router settings to open a settings page (e.g. Wi-Fi setting or ADSL settings):

```
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=286ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=605ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=839ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=2399ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.2: bytes=32 time=288ms TTL=64
```

-> Page finished loading

This has been going on for some time. Any ideas why this could happen?

Comment: What happens with a wired connection? Did you try resetting the router?

Comment: @DavidPostill wired connections - no issues, no lag, no problem at all, happens only with wired. Reset, well have done that many times, and many i mean alot!, no use...

Comment: Do you have any unrecognised wireless devices?

Comment: Do both the wireless Windows PC and the Android device see the same problems at the same time?

Comment: @Spiff thanks and sorry for delay,. yes all devices, linux, android and windows share the same issue, time outs and lag persists on all devices connect to the wifi network

Comment: @DavidPostill no, none, I would know too, have been keeping a very very close eye on that router ;P

Answer (score 0):

First, try changing the channel. It doesn't matter that it's on the same channel has worked in the past and you don't see any other *Wi-Fi* traffic on it. A non-Wi-Fi 2.4GHz device may have come up in the mean time and could be killing you. Maybe your next-door neighbor got a new baby monitor, cordless phone, wireless subwoofer, or Bluetooth speaker. I've specifically seen some chipsets that do proprietary (i.e. neither Wi-Fi nor Bluetooth) 2.4GHz wireless audio for things like wireless subwoofers hit a glitch where they will start transmitting a continuous high-power unmodulated carrier wave even when there's no audio being sent to the speakers. This basically jams any Wi-Fi channels that happen to overlap with the frequency of the carrier wave.

Second, as a test, disable 802.11 power save in the advanced driver settings of your client's Wi-Fi adapter. 802.11 power save mode can cause latency fluctuations, and, in conjunction with a buggy AP, can cause packet loss. Maybe an OS or driver update you forgot about enabled power save.

Third, check signal strength and data rate. Both the client's view of the AP, and the AP's view of the client. If the signal strength on either side looks ridiculously low, check to make sure your antennas (on each device) didn't become disconnected.

Comment: thanks for your answer, okay 1. the only possible interferances is a microsoft wireless k/b & mouse set which runs  on the 2.4/5 ghz band, i unplugged that, didnt help, have tried changing channels, doesnt help, and my channel 1 is clear from any other networks, closest netwrok has a 80-100dBm strength on channel 6, i can barely detect it. 2. This happens to all devices connected to wifi, on android, linux and windows, thus problem is not client related. 3 Wifi strentght at weakest is 68dBm, my room, and normally it is completely perfect, but now even standing by the router, time outs persist!

Comment: @K4GCybeX What are the exact models of the keyboard and mouse? I'd like to look up their specs, because dual-band HID seems unlikely to me. When you unplugged the receiver, did you also switch off both the keyboard and the mouse? When you tried changing channels, did you try channels that were as far as possible from the channel you started on (for example, if you started on channel 1, did you try channel 11)? Do you really live on a farm in the middle of nowhere with no one else around, or are you just pretending to know that your neighbors non-Wi-Fi 2.4GHz devices can't be interfering?

Comment: 1. Wireless Desktop 3000 2. Dongle unplugged aswel as switched off the k/b, no luck. I tried all channels, rebooting the router after each change (it actually reboots automatically). 3. Fact: neighbours use channel 6, thus it has no possibility of interferring since it hasnt for the past 4-6 years, and they have had the same router since. 4. At times,like this very moment my pc -> router ping is "normal" ranging (5-20ms), but at times, it request time out x1 or x2 then ping jumps to 500-3000ms, then request time outs x1 or x2, then <20ms again for a while, EDIT: 10s later ping jumped again